# How do I pass all values in an array as arguments one by one in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a menu for the user to choose which file he wants to view using dialog. The file names are stored in an array called 'fileNames'. I want to send them as arguments to the dialog command like this:

```
dialog --menu "Choose a file:" 20 50 ${#fileNames[@]} 1 <${fileNames[0]}> 2 <${fileNames[1]}> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should aim for a solution what will work with filenames containing special characters (spaces, even newlines).  What you can do is build a secondary array with all required strings, like this :

```
declare -i i=0
declare -a arguments=()
for file in "${fileNames[@]}" ; do
  arguments+=( $((++i)) "$file")
done
dialog --menu "Choose a file:" 20 50 "${arguments[@]}"
```

The double quotes around the `"${arguments[@]}"` array expansion are what prevent word splitting from occurring inside each individual elements and guarantees spaces and other special (but valid) characters in file names will not cause problems.

Please note this code assumes the `fileNames` array already exists and is not empty.  It also assumes the numbers passed to the `dialog` command are not the actual array indexes, but sequential and starting at 1.  If these are not correct assumptions, please comment and I can update the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way would be by using `${fileNames[@]}`.

```
dialog --menu "Choose a file:" 20 50 ${#fileNames[@]} 1 "${fileNames[@]}"
```

Edit: To add numbers in between each argument, I would use a `for` loop;

```
line="dialog --menu \"Choose a file:\" 20 50 ${#fileNames[@]}"
for ((i=0;i<${#fileNames[@]};i++)); do
    line="$line "$(($i + 1))
    line="$line " "${FileNames[$i]}"
done
$line #This will run the completed line built above
```

Comment: yeah, but I need to add numbers in between every file name

Comment: My mistake, one moment.